# Is there a way to send a message from a service worker to client in Safari (iOS)?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

When a network request fails due to being offline, I need to inform the client and update the DOM.

This is easy enough to do on browsers that support the BroadcastChannel API (as seen in the code example below), but I'm all out of ideas trying to figure out a workaround for getting this to work in iOS Safari.

A cache seems like the only obvious option in terms of communication between the service worker and the client but I'm not sure how I'd go about utilising a cache to do something like this as all the examples I've seen use the cache as a means to serve resources.

```
  // Clone the request to ensure it's safe to read when
  // adding to the Queue.
  const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone())
    .catch((err) => {
      isOffline = true;
      const bc = new BroadcastChannel('wb_channel');
      bc.postMessage('offline');
      return queue.pushRequest({ request: event.request });
    });
  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `postMessage` API. Using that you're able to pass messages between the client and the Service Worker.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/message_event